# What python MQTT client is in active production (python-mosquitto or paho-python)?

Tags: python, mqtt

I was using [python-mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org/documentation/python/) for several projects. Today I read that the Eclipse [Paho](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) project also contains a Python MQTT client module. I built and installed it, and the syntax and classes appear to be exactly the same.

Is one a fork of the other? Which one is under active development and should be used in production? [mqtt.org](http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/libraries) seems to think the Paho is the way to go but there is no mention of this on mosquitto.org.

What are the exact differences between python-mosquitto and paho-python?

Comment: Obviously one isn't a fork of the other, given that one is written in Python and the other in C. The reason they seem similar is that they're both MQTT implementations. As far as which one to use, asking for recommendations for third-party libraries or opinions about them is one of the things SO is specifically not good for—but the fact that Paho's front page says that its Python Client is "coming soon" implies to me that you don't want to use Paho for production code today…

Comment: I can provide an exact answer that is not based on opinions because I'm the author. This will cover both the reason for the difference and a solid explanation of which one to use.

Comment: The "coming soon" on the Paho website is referring to the documentation, which is available but not through the website.

Comment: ralight, I would be very interested to hear your answer and thoughts. paho-python does indeed already exist. Perhaps if I reword my question to only ask what the difference is between the two clients, that is not a question of opinion.

Comment: I donated the mosquitto Python client to Paho. That's why they're basically identical. I've kept mosquitto.py going because it's widely used, but you'd be better off moving to Paho. It's quite easy to move between them.